# How to reload/refresh an html file from another html file using javascript when a specific condition is true?

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements, reload

here I try to demonstrate my problem ,I have one **main** html file and two **sub** html files included inside the **main** file,the second **sub** html page is initially invisible .if the the value submitted on the input box of first **sub** html page is equal to 5 ,then the second **sub** html file is become visible and first **sub** file hided.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function(){
    //console.log(document.getElementById('input-box').value);
    if(document.getElementById('input-box').value == 5){
        document.getElementById('sub1').classList.add('none');
        //here before showing the div#sub2 part ,i would like to reload the aboutus.php or one js file aboutus.js
        document.getElementById('sub2').classList.remove('none');
    
    }
});
```

```css
.none{
  display:none;
}

#main{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

#main>div{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="sub1">
    <h7>page 1</h7>
    <input type="number" id="input-box"/>
    <button id="button">click</button>
  </div>
  <div id="sub2" class="none">
    <h7>page 2</h7>
    <?php include "aboutus.html"; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

what I would like to achieve is reload the second **sub** html page once before the second **sub** file is visible.because there are lot of database changes occur in the second **sub** file and a reload can fix this issue.

what I have tried so far ,`window.onload`this will not work because window (second sub file)is loaded initially .`window.location.reload()` is also not working because that can be used to reload the same file.anybody have tricks to solve this ?

Comment: You can't reload part of a page like that; what you want to do is use AJAX to request the data again and then write it to that div. Look up AJAX techniques.